# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) from /system/lib/libhwui.so

Tags: android, android-runtime, oboe

This issue arises from the android run time.
Any idea what this is ?

I am using native code here which plays an audio file in the background. When I just start to play around with the ui of the app this issue pops up.

The app works fine in android 7 but breaks on android 10 specially on samsung devices.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:10/QSR1.191030.002/5978551:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
Timestamp: 2020-02-19 00:21:31+0530
pid: 10918, tid: 10933, name: ReferenceQueueD  >>> com.myapp.beta <<<
uid: 10133
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xbe04dbc0
    eax be04dbbc  ebx f1f2f9ac  ecx 70bc7ba8  edx 00000000
    edi 12f0fb10  esi df165880
    ebp cc0d15e8  esp cc0d15d0  eip f1976406

backtrace:
      #00 pc 001f1406  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkPaint::~SkPaint()+150) (BuildId: 10d1e316b7aa14d35052a448bd944fde)
      #01 pc 002dbd74  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::Paint::~Paint()+52) (BuildId: 10d1e316b7aa14d35052a448bd944fde)
      #02 pc 00162bd5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::PaintGlue::deletePaint(android::Paint*)+37) (BuildId: 6ceb9761bceb97a18c92f8a4b7072247)
      #03 pc 0003601e  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libjavacore.so (NativeAllocationRegistry_applyFreeFunction(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long long, long long)+30) (BuildId: 688305bcfab3d72450178332b5c29bc2)
      #04 pc 0004e652  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (art_jni_trampoline+178) (BuildId: 6e90a1c34e5945941f1d1cb9bac9218325a4cd49)
      #05 pc 0203d82a  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry$CleanerThunk.run+122)
      #06 pc 0209a2cc  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (sun.misc.Cleaner.clean+92)
      #07 pc 020a77bf  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueueLocked+239)
      #08 pc 020aabae  /memfd:/jit-cache (deleted) (java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueuePending+174)
      #09 pc 0013e9a2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #10 pc 00149a7a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+298) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #11 pc 00332502  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+386) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #12 pc 0032c19c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+988) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #13 pc 00684d03  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+643) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #14 pc 001389a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+33) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #15 pc 001b4104  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal+52)
      #16 pc 00681adc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1612) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #17 pc 00138821  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+33) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #18 pc 001b382e  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+50)
      #19 pc 006837bc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1980) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #20 pc 00138a21  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+33) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #21 pc 000ea918  /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar (java.lang.Thread.run+8)
      #22 pc 002f8e0a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.6689468213397061768+298) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #23 pc 002ffcc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+181) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #24 pc 0066fbd9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1209) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #25 pc 0014503d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #26 pc 0013e7d2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #27 pc 00149a69  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+281) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #28 pc 0055a513  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+99) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #29 pc 0055b91a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+474) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #30 pc 005aaa51  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1585) (BuildId: a0a062684495092d1756e30ba2dff37d)
      #31 pc 0011a8e5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
      #32 pc 000af6a7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71) (BuildId: 76290498408016ad14f4b98c3ab6c65c)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in the background"? Does your app's UI also go into the background when you're playing audio? Also, please could you check the [RhythmGame sample app](https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/RhythmGame) to see whether it also crashes.

Comment: Hi @donturner , it doesn't go in the background. When I set audio Api as OpenSLES this doesn't crash.

Comment: Please post the code you're using to play the sound.

Comment: @donturner Which part of the code would you like to see ? The audio ready callback ? Can you just point me to what could be the possible issue here. I am unable to pin point the issue

Comment: Also, one thing I have observed that we are using soundtouch in audio ready callback to realtime process the tempo of the audio. If I stop using this library and play plain audio from file then this doesn't crash.

Comment: @Sarasranglt were you able to solve this issue ?